# An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine when running a socket program

Tags: python

So I'm making a game with my friend. And i have a client+server code for it.
The server part works fine,
but whenever I run the client, it returns an error(python3.10, win10 64bit):

```
An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine
```

server.py:

```
import socket
import sys
import threading
import os
import random as rand
HOST = ''  
PORT = 7474
os.system('title GunLord server vBETA')
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
print('# Socket created')
try:
    s.bind((HOST, PORT))
except socket.error as msg:
    print('# Bind failed. ')
    sys.exit()

print('# Socket bind complete')
s.listen(100)
print('# Socket now listening')

def clientThread(conn, addr, playerID):
    global PlayerLocationData
    print('# Connected to ' + addr[0] + ':' + str(addr[1]))
    try:
        while True:
            data = conn.recv(1024)
            line = data.decode('UTF-8')
            clientData = line.split('&')
            PlayerLocationData[playerID] = str(clientData[0]) +'.'+str(clientData[1])+'.'+str(clientData[2])
            responsePlayerLocationData = ''
            for i in range(len(PlayerLocationData)):
                responsePlayerLocationData +=PlayerLocationData[i]+'%%'
            try:
                conn.send(str(responsePlayerLocationData).encode())
            except:
                PlayerLocationData[playerID] = None
    except:
        conn.close()
threads = []
global PlayerLocationData
PlayerLocationData = []
while True:
    conn, addr = s.accept()
    playerID = rand.randint(1, 1000)
    t = threading.Thread(target=clientThread(conn, addr, playerID))
    t.start()
    threads.append(t)


s.close()
```

client.py:

```
import socket
import random as rand
import time as t
host = '127.0.0.1'
port = 7474
s = socket.socket()
s.connect((host, port))
global PlayerLocations
PlayerLocations = []
def recvDecoder(recvText):
    global PlayerLocations
    PlayerLocations = recvText.split('%%')
while True:
    testX = rand.randint(1, 10)
    testY = rand.randint(1, 10)
    testZ = rand.randint(1, 10)
    print('test coords: {}, {}, {}' .format(testX, testY, testZ))
    s.send('{}&{}&{}'.format(testX, testY, testZ).encode())
    data = s.recv(1024)
    line = data.decode('UTF-8')
    recvDecoder(line)
    t.sleep(.3)
```

Full traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\---\Desktop\---\---\testClient.py", line 19, in <module>
    data = s.recv(1024)
ConnectionAbortedError: [WinError 10053] An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [tour] and read [ask]. Questions here must be self-contained; we're not going to go off-site and dig through your code. Please [edit] your question and include the relevant code _here_, directly in your question.

Comment: @Chris if I paste the code here, it won't let me post it because I have "too much code"

Comment: So trim it down. We don't need everything, just a [mre]. Again, please read [ask].

Comment: @Chris Well, i reduced it as much as i could

Comment: Thank you. Now, can you provide more information about the error? Does it reference a line number and include a traceback?

Comment: @Chris I did that